# SOGo ugly GUI over the internet

Tags: mail-server, roundcube, iredmail

I searched all over the inet but still could not find an answer to my problem. I have a mail server (iRedMail) which runs on both SOGo and Roundcube. Roundcube runs just fine, the problem comes when I try to access my SOGo interface over the internet I get this:
[SOGo interface over the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfz3n.png)

Whilst running same mail server over the local network I get a normal picture like this:
[SOGo on the local network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOFXF.png)

My webserver is certified by Let'sEncrypt, my NAT rules are fine, as well as Firewall rules (80,443,25,53).
If someone had same problem, please help, thank you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about programming.

Comment: am I supposed to have exceptionnaly questions on codeing?

Comment: Yes. There are other Web sites for other types of questions. Try https://serverfault.com/ for yours.

Comment: Thank you very much